# How to make the $ y $-axis of a spectrogram logarithmic?

Tags: logarithmic-scale

Is there a way to make the $ y $-axis for a spectrogram logarithmic? I couldn't find an option for it and was doing it explicitly.

Consider for e.g. the spectrogram of [this audio](https://youtu.be/HiH4_A0xq40):

[image: spectrogram]

which after log adjustment would look like

[image: logAdjustedSpectrogram]

Comment: Have you tried `Spectrogram[audio, Method -> "MelFrequency"]` ? That's log scaled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the Mel scale:

```
Spectrogram[audio, Method -> {"MelFrequency", 100, 100, 7000}, 
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, AspectRatio -> 1/5]
```

[image: mel spectrogram]

Or you can construct an `Image` and apply a non-linear transformation. I've used `FourierParameters->{0,1}` as it makes the image more crisp and it's a bit easier to notice that they're storm troopers from Star Wars:

```
spec = SpectrogramArray[audio, FourierParameters -> {0, 1}];
(* cut the data in half and take the Abs *)
img = Image[Map[Abs, Reverse[Transpose[spec][[1 ;; Round[Length[spec]/2]]]], {2}]];
(* move pixels to log position in y-coordinate *)
ImageForwardTransformation[img, {#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]*1308]/Log[1308]/2} &]
```

[image: spectro image]

Comment: thnx...i was using an explicit log on values which was taking a lot of time. You went further and improved the spectrogram itself. I have credited you here https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/100405/60449. btw, you might cosider removing the youtube download instruction.